# how to solve this Jquery error?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have made some Jquery that you can see with this fiddle below: 
http://madaxedesign.co.uk/dev/Test/
http://jsfiddle.net/x82mU/1/

Code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var $root = $('html, body ');
$('.scroll a').click(function(e) {
    var href = $.attr(this, 'href');
    $root.animate({
        scrollTop: $(href).offset().top
    }, 500, function () {
        window.location.hash = href;
    });
    return false;
});

// Responsive menu 
$(function() {
    var pull        = $('#pull'),
        menu        = $('nav ul'),
        menuHeight  = menu.height()

    $(pull).on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        menu.slideToggle();
    });

    $(window).resize(function(){
        var w = $(window).width();
        if(w > 320 && menu.is(':hidden')) {
            menu.removeAttr('style');
        }
    });
}); 
 });
```

But it pulls through with this error: 
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined

This is preventing my next piece of Jquery to work.

I was wondering if anyone could let me know why, or give me a solution?

Many Thanks

Comment: it is `$(this).attr('href')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to get the selector from `href` which isn't there in many of your menu items.

i.e:

```
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#aboutUs">About us</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>        
    <li><a href="#">Contact us</a></li>
```

and

```
$(href).offset().top //here offset() of an empty jquery object is undefined.
```

Not an issue but you can just do `this.href` instead `$.attr(this, 'href')`

Try this:

```
 $('.scroll a').click(function(e) {
    var href = $(this).attr("href"), $el = $(href), top=0; //default top to 0
       if($el.length)  //if there is element matching the href
          top = $el.offset().top; //set the top
    $root.animate({
        scrollTop: top //now scroll
    }, 500, function () {
        window.location.hash = href;
    });
    return false;
});
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/X443X/)**

Comment: so should i put .offset(href) so that it has something to identify it?

Comment: @MaxwellLynn What are you trying to do? You dont have element specified as href in many of the menu items.

Comment: I'm trying to get the about us link to scroll nicely instead of jumping to the about us part of the page. Which is seems to be doing well. However I have the error stated above that is breaking my next piece of code that is a drop down navigation which is used for mobile. You can see this in action from the madaxedesign link supplied if you minimize the screen

Comment: @MaxwellLynn You need to handle the `#` scenario, see my answer updated.

Answer (score 1):

```
var href = $(this).attr('href');
```

*update as comment*

for

```
scrollTop: $(href).offset().top
```

to work, the

```
href
```

variable has to be an element on page.

so if your link is like

```
<a href="#an_id_to_a_div">...</a>
```

it will be fine.

jquery dom object creation

```
 $(dom_element)
```

targets html tags, classes, id's or existing Dom objects ( window, document .. )

Comment: Thats for helping but that has kept the same error preventing it from reading the next piece of Jquery. Is it possible you may know another reason?